# When added ngModel to Radio Button default checked is not working in angular 6

Tags: angular

When adding ngModel to radio button the default checked is not working.If ngmodel is not used checked is working.But I want both the options.There are lot of questions related to this but no one solution is worked for me then only I raise new question.If anyone clarify why the checked is not working when adding ngModel and what is the solution for this?

```
   Tried code:     

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_default_inline" id="defaultInlineRadio1" value="" [(ngModel)]="name.Status"[checked]="!isChecked">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultInlineRadio1">Active</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_default_inline" id="defaultInlineRadio2" value [(ngModel)]="name.Status">            
              <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultInlineRadio1">Inactive</label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Another Method:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_default_inline" id="defaultInlineRadio1" value="Active" [(ngModel)]="name.Status">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultInlineRadio1">Active</label>       

              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_default_inline" id="defaultInlineRadio2" value="InActive" [(ngModel)]="name.Status">
 <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultInlineRadio1">Inactive</label>
```

AnotherMethod:

```
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_default_inline" id="defaultInlineRadio1" value="Active" checked [(ngModel)]="name.Status">
                          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultInlineRadio1">Active</label>       

                          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_default_inline" id="defaultInlineRadio2" value="InActive" [(ngModel)]="name.Status">
             <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultInlineRadio1">Inactive</label

    ts:

        this.name.Status = 'Active';
```

Another Method:

```
         <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_default_inline" id="defaultInlineRadio1" value="ngModel" checked [(ngModel)]="name.Status">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultInlineRadio1">Active</label>       

                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_default_inline" id="defaultInlineRadio2" value="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="name.Status">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultInlineRadio1">Inactive</label
```

I want both defalut checked option and binding to be works.How to achieve this?Don't say duplicate question I tried all the solution related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

How would you expect the value of the checkbox to be determined? Is the model leading or is the checked property leading? And how is Angular supposed to figure this one out? Quick answer: Angular considers your model leading, and thus your checked property doesn't work. You'll have to simply modify your model in your ts file instead of using the checked property.

Like:

```
set isChecked(checked: boolean) {
   this._isChecked = checked;
   this.name.Status = checked;
}
```

One more thing; you'll obviously have to set the value for the radio buttons. For my example to true and false.

Comment: Can you add example for this.

Comment: Why you used two variables isChecked and _isChecked

Comment: isChecked became a setter method; if you want to maintain the actual value you'll have to store it in a (private) variable.

Comment: What is not working? What does your code look like? And did you add the values to the radio buttons in your template?

Comment: Yes added the value in template also.radio button is not checked by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with syntax

```
[(ngModel)] = "nameVariable"
[value]= 113 // typeof = number
// or
[value]= "option-1" // typeof = string
```